# Не повторяющиеся значения. SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Как сделать, что-бы значения не повторялись при выборке? 
distinct не помогает.

## Запрос

```
select distinct ot.code,
cp.Description,
ml.Phone

from dwh.dim.dimCatalogCounterparties cp with (nolock)
join markets.dbo.otkreplen ot with (nolock) on ot.code = cp.Code collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
join dwh.dm.CounterpartySegmentMainLink_Arc ml with (nolock) on ml.iCounterpartyID = cp.iCounterpartiesID
```

## Результат

```
code    Description Phone
101-00003362    ПП Школьний Дмитрий 380663984155
101-00003362    ПП Школьний Дмитрий 380675636350
101-00003362    ПП Школьний Дмитрий 380675636354
101-00003362    ПП Школьний Дмитрий 380675729293
101-00003362    ПП Школьний Дмитрий 380973470838
101-00004499    ГЕДЕОН ДТ   380509107240
101-00004499    ГЕДЕОН ДТ   380542658701
```

Comment: Поясните , что значит distinct не помогает? вообще не работает или возвращает что то не то ? ( желательно с примерами , что возвращает и что должен на ваш взгляд) ps distinct относится ко всему запросу а не только к первому полю.

Comment: возвращает задвоенные данные с повторением, code, description, phone. code, заапдейтил.

Comment: Ну так phone то разный. distinct относится ко всем полям

Comment: а каким образом мне можно получить данные, которые не будут повторятся ?

Comment: Какие колонки не должны повторяться? что должно быть в остальных колонках?

Comment: Просто выбрать по 1 уникальной записи. 1 код, 1 описание, 1 телефон.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38385/discussion-between-batanichek-and-niflungar).

Comment: если к 'ПП Школьний Дмитрий' относится 5 номеров телефонов - то какой из них показывать?     distinct работает верно - показывает все запрашиваемые комбинации, все разные, уникальные. Если телефон не интересен - то убери его из списка выводимых полей, или как ответе, данном Batanichek - покажи один из них

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно вот так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ot.code,
                cp.[Description],
                STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '; ' + ml.Phone
                FROM dwh.dm.CounterpartySegmentMainLink_Arc ml with (nolock) 
                WHERE ml.iCounterpartyID = cp.iCounterpartiesID
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'') as phones
FROM dwh.dim.dimCatalogCounterparties cp with (nolock)
INNER JOIN markets.dbo.otkreplen ot with (nolock) on ot.code = cp.Code collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

На выходе:

```
code         Description         phones
------------ ------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------
101-00003362 ПП Школьний Дмитрий 380663984155; 380675636350; 380675636354; 380675729293; 380973470838
101-00004499 ГЕДЕОН ДТ           380509107240; 380542658701

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вот так

```
select ot.code,
cp.Description,
max(ml.Phone) Phone

from  dwh.dim.dimCatalogCounterparties cp with (nolock)
join markets.dbo.otkreplen ot with (nolock) on ot.code = cp.Code collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
join dwh.dm.CounterpartySegmentMainLink_Arc ml with (nolock) on ml.iCounterpartyID = cp.iCounterpartiesID
group by ot.code,cp.Description
```